# Single-word metaphor that means "to be very bad at?"

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> Metaphors. I always been a [...] at deciphering them."

I think I'm looking for the antonym of whiz, but when I checked them on [Thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/whiz), I didn't find anything that could fit the sentence. Any suggestions?

(I thought of chickenhead, but I think it's also a derogatory term.)

Comment: Anything like *dunce* ought to do: "Metaphors. I've always been a dunce at deciphering them."

Comment: You might struggle to find a non-derogatory term for someone who's incompetent.  'Novice' might be fairly neutral, but (obviously) infers a lack of experience which may not be what you're after.

Comment: If you can't find a suitable noun, suggest: 'I've always been *useless* or *crap* at deciphering them.'

Comment: Klutz -- "I've always been a klutz at deciphering them"
Useless -- "I've always been useless at deciphering them"

Comment: I guess 'left shark' never caught on.

Comment: "Metaphors. I suck at deciphering them." Vulgar unless your audience has the same problem as you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(warning: non-native here) I'd say

> Metaphors. I have always been *horrible* at deciphering them

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat impolite and non-single-word from *Macmillan dictionary*:

**[Piss artist](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/someone-who-is-bad-at-doing-something)**

> someone who does something very badly

Comment: I've only ever heard that to mean 'very heavy drinker' (in the UK).

Answer (score 1):

I would use *[duffer](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/duffer)* for that purpose:-

> 1. a dull or incompetent person [Collins English Dictionary via the Free Dictionary]

One might say *I have always been a duffer at rocket science*.

Answer (score 1):

**a jackass**, **a blockhead**, **a chowderhead**, **a dummy**, **a dumbbell**, **etc...**

They all mean stupid.

Answer (score 0):

I have always been **such a dummy** at deciphering them.

[image]